# Kafka - Issue after creating kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 3 zookeeper instances and 3 kafka instances.

The configuration is all fine and i can see they are properly connected to each other.

Then I create a new topic using below command :

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 10.XXX.XXX.XX:2181,10.XXX.XXX.XX:2182,10.XXX.XXX.XX:2183 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic <topicName>
```

But as soon as i create a consumer using :

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 
10.XXX.XXX.XX:9094,10.XXX.XXX.XX:9095,10.XXX.XXX.XX:9096 --topic ankit108 - 
consumer-property group.id=test1
```

I get below errors:

```
ERROR [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=2, fetcherId=0] Error for 
partition __consumer_offsets-32 to broker 
2:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This 
server does not host this topic-partition. 
(kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

Comment: Can you describe the __consumer_offsets topic?